# Math operators on window partitions

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to get the time difference

```
lead(time) - time
```

This doesn't work:

```
SELECT 
the_geom,
id,
lat,
lng,
mapid,
time,
lead(time) - time  // THIS DOESNT WORK
OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY time ASC)
as duration

FROM history
```

But this works:

```
SELECT 
the_geom,
id,
lat,
lng,
mapid,
time,
-time + lead(time)   // THIS WORKS
OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY time ASC)
as duration

FROM history
```

The first one gives the error:

```
Syntax error near OVER
```

I don't know why this is the case, can anyone explain?

Comment: Please define `doesn't work` BTW: `time` is a reserved word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Window functions have two parts

the first part is a function expression similar to aggregate functions, e.g.

```
Sum(revenue)
row_number()
rank()
```

this part has to be followed by an `OVER clause`. In your case

```
OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY time ASC)
```

The window function is made by putting the two together, e.g.

```
SUM(revenue) OVER (PARTITION BY department 
                   ORDER BY created_month 
                   ROWS BETWEEN UNBUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
-- this calculates the running total for fictitious `departments` 
-- over months
```

Your first query doesn't do that, the 2nd does, because SQL ignores new lines when it evaluates expression